# JSF 2.0; Validator tag "disabled" depends on value from page

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

In my jsf application i want to validate a field which should only be validated, when one option in a SelectOneRadio is checked.

I found out, that `<f:validator>` has an attribute, called "disabled".

Can i use this, to check the value from another field?

I tried, but i haven't access to the value from my bean.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.valuesForSelectOneRadio}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>


<f:validator validatorId="myValidator" disabled="#{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue == 'TEST'}" />
```

Is there any way to reach that without writing own validatorhandler?

Thanks!

Comment: Your check for disabled looks somewhat suspicious, shouldn't it be #{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue == 'TEST' }" or is it just a typo (moved curly brace)?

Comment: I tried your version too and it doesn't work. Could it be, that in that moment of validation the value from the SelectOneRadio isn't stored in the bean?

Comment: Try setting partialSubmit="true" in the selectOneRadio Tag, that should sumit the value.

Comment: Does partialSubmit exists on myfaces or is there an alternative?

Comment: I could not use ajax. the validator is in another field, which should only be validated, if in selectoneradio a specific value is selected

Answer (score 11):

The `<f:validator>` is a tag handler, not an UI component. All its attributes are per definition evaluated during view build time, not during view render time. The view build time is that moment when the XHTML file is been parsed into a JSF component tree as available by `context.getViewRoot()`. The very same view is usually reused across postbacks to the same view by returning `null`/`void` in (ajax) actions.

So you can't let a tag handler attribute depend on a render time attribute which can change during a postback request. One of the ways is to perform that check inside the custom validator itself.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText>
    <f:validator validatorId="myValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="radio" value="#{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue}" />
</h:inputText>
```

with

```
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {     
    if (!"TEST".equals(component.getAttributes().get("radio"))) {
        return;
    }

    // Perform actual validation here.
}
```

You can alternatively also use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:validator>`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/o/validator.html) instead. It extends the standard `<f:validator>` with request based evaluation of EL in attributes.

```
<h:inputText>
    <o:validator validatorId="myValidator" disabled="#{bean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue == 'TEST'}" />
</h:inputText>
```

See also the [showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/validator) and the [source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/org/omnifaces/taghandler/Validator.java) from which an extract of relevance is posted below:

```
@Override
public void apply(FaceletContext context, UIComponent parent) throws IOException {
    if (!ComponentHandler.isNew(parent)) {
        return;
    }

    final javax.faces.validator.Validator validator = createValidator(context);
    final RenderTimeAttributes attributes = collectRenderTimeAttributes(context, validator);
    final ValueExpression disabled = getValueExpression(context, "disabled", Boolean.class);
    ((EditableValueHolder) parent).addValidator(new javax.faces.validator.Validator() {

        @Override
        public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
            if (disabled == null || Boolean.FALSE.equals(disabled.getValue(context.getELContext()))) {
                attributes.invokeSetters(context.getELContext(), validator);
                validator.validate(context, component, value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `<o:validator>` made my day!

Answer (score 0):

With JSF 2.0 you can use `f:ajax` for a partial submit. Add this tag to your `h:selectOneRadio`:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue}">
    <f:ajax render="idOfInputText"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.valuesForSelectOneRadio}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
...
<h:inputText id="idOfInputText">
    <f:validator validatorId="myValidator" 
                 disabled="#{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue eq 'TEST'}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Replace the `render`attribute content with the real id of your input field with the validator. This assumes that the selectOneRadio and the inputText are inside the same NamingContainer.

Comment: I tried this example too, but it doesn't work. Now i believe, there is something strange going on here :-/ Do i have to use binding for selectoneradio and/or inputtext?

Comment: Finally, i found a solution.
I'm going to validate now in myBean and everything works as expected.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score -1):

To avoid extended discussions in comments, i will provide my suggestions as an answer to discuss it further...

At first it should be

`disabled="#{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue == 'TEST'}`

or

`disabled="#{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue eq 'TEST'}`

Additional, at least in ICEFaces (and MyFaces should have this function, too), you may use:

`<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.checkedSelectOneRadioValue}" partialSubmit="true">
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.valuesForSelectOneRadio}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>`

This should force an ajax request after changing the value of selectoneradio and the validator-disabled check should be able to get it from the bean.

If that does not work, there may be autoSubmit or similar in MyFaces...

Comment: Does not work :-( I tried with partialSubmit, with eq and with ==, but the validator will not work as i expect. At least, i tried to set 'TEST' to null, and it worked. The selected Value will not be written to the bean. Can i use a valueChangeListener to store the value in the bean?

Comment: In which component do you use the validator? Does it have partialSubmits, immediates or whatever? Is the new value not written into your bean or does your view not receive it back from it?

Comment: The validator is in an inputText. Should there also be the partialSubmit attribute?

Comment: `partialSubmit` only exist in ICEfaces components of `<ice:xxx>` family. The OP did not indicate in any way that s/he is using ICEfaces. In standard JSF2, there's the `<f:ajax>` which does that job.

Comment: So, what do you use? MyFaces or Standard JSF or what? <t:xxx>, <tr:xxx>? And why <h:selectOneRadio> and not <tr:selectOneRadio>? Trinidad may have auto submits, other may have similar features like <f:ajax>...